# Telerik RadPersistenceManager Unable to read storage content

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've used RadPersistenceManager with asp.net and follow the following guide :

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/persistence-framework/examples/custom-storage-provider/defaultcs.aspx.

But when I implement this in my project the following exception appears:

> Title: xxxx.aspx, xxxxx Method Name:
>   Unable to read storage content. Could not find file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\XXXX\App_Data\TelerikAspNetRadControlsPersistedState'.
>
> Exception:    at
>   Telerik.Web.UI.PersistenceFramework.AppDataStorageProvider.LoadStateFromStorage(String
>   key)    at  Telerik.Web.UI.RadPersistenceManager.LoadState()    at GraphicalUserInterface.JobBasket.LoadGridJobBasket()

Comment: Please post your code that's producing this error.

Comment: The same code in the above guide except that RadScriptManager is in the master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different between the demo and my example that I need to load the persistence configurations on page load instead of load button. so it seems some times the CookieStorageProvider not initiated in Page_Init, so I added it in page_load instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default storage provider key. If the control is looking for it, then your custom provider is not in effect at all.

Make sure you have everything from the demo, primarily:

the lines that set the custom storage provider:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadPersistenceManager1.StorageProviderKey = CookieName;
    RadPersistenceManager1.StorageProvider = new CookieStorageProvider(CookieName);
}
```

and the custom storage provider itself:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Web.UI.PersistenceFramework;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;

public class CookieStorageProvider : IStateStorageProvider
{
    private static readonly Encoding AsciiEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
    private static readonly int MaxCookieSize = 4000;
    private static readonly int LengthDataByteCount = sizeof(Int32);
    private string StorageKey { get; set; }

    #region IStateStorageProvider

    public CookieStorageProvider(string key)
    {
        StorageKey = key;
    }

    public void SaveStateToStorage(string key, string serializedState)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(StorageKey);
        string settingsData = CompressString(serializedState);

        if (settingsData.Length > MaxCookieSize)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Current settings exceed 4k in compressed form! Operation canceled!");
        }

        cookie.Value = settingsData;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    public string LoadStateFromStorage(string key)
    {
        return DecompressString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[StorageKey].Value.ToString());
    }

    #endregion

    private string CompressString(string inputString)
    {
        byte[] outputBytes = null;
        byte[] inputBytes = AsciiEncoding.GetBytes(inputString);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                zipStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
            }
            outputBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(AddDataCount(outputBytes, inputBytes.Length));
    }

    private string DecompressString(string inputString)
    {
        string outputString = String.Empty;
        byte[] inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);
        Int32 lengthDataArray = BitConverter.ToInt32(inputBytes, inputBytes.Length - LengthDataByteCount);
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[lengthDataArray];

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(RemoveDataCount(inputBytes)))
        {
            using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                zipStream.Read(outputBytes, 0, outputBytes.Length);
            }
            outputString = AsciiEncoding.GetString(outputBytes);
        }

        return outputString;
    }

    private byte[] AddDataCount(byte[] inputArray, Int32 length)
    {
        byte[] lengthDataArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
        Array.Resize<byte>(ref inputArray, inputArray.Length + LengthDataByteCount);
        Array.Copy(lengthDataArray, 0, inputArray, inputArray.Length - LengthDataByteCount, LengthDataByteCount);
        return inputArray;
    }

    private byte[] RemoveDataCount(byte[] inputArray)
    {
        Array.Resize<byte>(ref inputArray, inputArray.Length - LengthDataByteCount);
        return inputArray;
    }
}
```